# Return all lists and their contents from a YAML file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to write a custom yaml lint rule for lists. However, I cannot figure out how to get just the lists from the file.

For example if I have the following files:

variables1.yaml:

```yaml
---
list1:
  - list1value1
  - list1value2
  - list1value3
string1: this_is_a_string
bool1: true
list2:
  - list2value1
  - list2value2
  - list2value3
```

variables2.yaml:

```
---
dict1:
  dict1list1:
    - dict1list1value1
    - dict1list1value2
  dict1bool1: false
bool2: true
list3:
  - list3value1
  - list3value2
  - list3value3
list4:
  - list4value1
  - list4value2
```

Then what I would want is:

```py
>>> for name, values in get_lists_from_yaml_file("variable1.yaml"):
    print(name: values)

list1: ['list1value1', 'list1value2', 'list1value3']
list2: ['list2value1', 'list2value2', 'list2value3']

>>> for name, values in get_lists_from_yaml_file("variables2.yaml"):
    print(name: values)

dict1list1: ['dict1list1value1', 'dict1list1value2']
list3: ['list3value1', 'list3value2', 'list3value3']
list4: ['list4value1', 'list4value2']
```

Additional nice to have: line number where the list is declared

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show the code you’ve written, because StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service and you are like to get down- and close-votes if you don’t show an honest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Once the yaml is loaded, we have a python dict. We iterate over the dict items and check which value is a list.

Try the below

```
import yaml

with open('variables1.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            print(f'{k} --> {v}')
```

output

```
list1 --> ['list1value1', 'list1value2', 'list1value3']
list2 --> ['list2value1', 'list2value2', 'list2value3']
```